Compare the contents of a file with a variable
I have written content to a text file, from inside Robot Framework.
How can I compare the contents of the text file I just generated with a variable?
This is how I created the text file - With the declaration of this keyword:
Write String To File
    ${Mystring}=    Set Variable    justRandomContent
    Create File    P=file=${CURDIR}/data/.txt    ${Mystring}

And this is how I unsuccessfully tried to perform the comparison (from inside a Test Case):
Write String To File
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${P}    ${expectedValue}    strip_spaces=True

The ${expectedValue} is the variable I want to compare the text file with, and it's declared elsewhere in the robot file.

Here is a modification of your code.
Write String To File
    Set Suite Variable    \${PathToFile}    ${CURDIR}/data/.txt
    ${Mystring}=    Set Variable    justRandomContent
    Create File    ${PathToFile}    ${Mystring}

Your keyword must not have the same name of other. You should probably clean the content read from file at ${P} to be sure it contains the content you need. There are some keyword in the String library, for example Get Lines Containing String.
Validate String At File
    ${P}=    Get File    ${PathToFile}
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${P}    ${expectedValue}    strip_spaces=True

